# mysqli doesn't connect under apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache, codeigniter, mysqli

I have a php application based on codeigniter, and I have a database that is located on remote host with required database installed, setup proper mysql permissions and with mysql port open for remote connections, however, when I run the application it doesn't work and it returns 500 error code.

When I troubleshoot the problem, it gives below error

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.6.13' (13)

what I have tried so far:

1) make sure all permissions are set correctly.

2) make sure no network related issues are existed such as blocked ports/hosts

3) make sure mysqli is installed and enabled.

4) created a connection test php script and ran it from the command line and it works just fine.

5) the fun part was when I ran the application from command line and it worked correctly as root user and as apache user as `su -s /bin/sh apache -c "php index.php".`

parameters I have:

1) php version is PHP 5.4.16

2) OS version: CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) on both web and DB

3) web server version Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

4) mysql  Ver 14.14

5) I run my app under ssl, and below is my configurations

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        #### Gloabl config
     DocumentRoot /var/www/bein
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     ServerName beinmob.com
     ServerAlias www.beinmob.com
        #### change basic URL to /index.php/POS_Admin/Session
     RewriteEngine  on
     RewriteRule ^/?$  index.php/POS_Admin/Session [R]
        #### change url to alias for web services
     Alias /web-services /var/www/bein/index.php
     Alias /POS_Admin /var/www/bein/
        #### Basic Authentication for /web-services url
        <Location /POS_Admin>
                RewriteEngine on
                # Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
                RewriteBase /index.php
                RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
        </Location>
        <Location /web-services>
                AuthName bein
                AuthType Basic
                AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/beinServicePass
                Require valid-user
        </Location>
        #### SSL configuration
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/cert/certs/www_beinmob_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/cert/certs/www_beinmob_com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/cert/certs/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: your apache configuration is irrelevant. apache has nothing to do with php trying to connect to mysql. either your mysql isn't listening for TCP connections, it's not listening on that particular IP, or you're using the wrong IP, or the IP is firewalled somehow.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/503489/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-13-using-php-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.filonov.com/2009/08/07/sqlstatehy000-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-13/)  it should solve your problem .

**Update because the link may become dead if that page moves or is deleted**

Login as root and do

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Comment: *Check this it should solve your problem .* ~ Hi Mr @Drudge, I think you have enough reputation to give suggestion in comment box. Right ? This is not an answer. Please don't use Answer section For Comment.

Comment: Dear @NanaPartykar , i think it is what the OP wants, so i write it in the answer section . Will it cause the problem ??

Comment: This is not an answer. This is just  a suggestion for OP to go through it. I don't see any code written over here in your answer. See in comment section, how Mr @Bogdan Burim gave link to OP.

Comment: ok i will improve from next time and thank you for your suggestion .

Comment: it seems its SElinux isssue, I changed it from enforced to permissise and rebooted the machine and all went well, thanks, and btw, it just came to my mind it could be a SElinux issue just right before I read your answer :P

Comment: @Drudge - the problem is that the link you posted here may become dead if that page moves or is deleted. much better to copy/paste the page content here (and give credit if you want).

Answer (score 0):

You have to checkout, if you can access to the myslq server from the terminal :

```
mysql -u youruser -h 192.168.0.3 -p
```

and see if you can login

It seems that you haven't got a connection, and it's not a problem with apache.
mysql server serve by default the port : `3306`
and apache 80 http, 443 https (for example. Some application like ispconfig run on 8080 and several application servers tomcat 81... ...)
But it seems not to be your case

Answer (score 0):

Make Privileges for Your Database .

[image]

enter any username

host must be %

and enter any password

after that use this privileges in your db config file .. sure you will get a access to your remote host db